# Custom font sizes inside section titles

Tags: sectioning, errors, fontsize

I need to change the size of some text within a section title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \section{This text is normal {\Large This text is large}}
\end{document}
```

This works, however, in some situations, I am using an extra-small font. For example:

```
\def\Tiny{ \font\Tinyfont = cmr10 at 5pt \relax  \Tinyfont}
```

When `\Tiny` is used within the section title, it produces:

> Undefined control sequence

- How can I get the `\Tiny` letters to appear in the section titles
- As the section title text is normally larger than regular text, but `\Tiny` letters also appear throughout the document, how can I ensure that the `Tiny` text within the section title is proportionally small (i.e. slightly larger than the `\Tiny` text within the rest of the document).

Comment: What are you writing!? It's got to be a thesis. It seems like you're popping up every five minutes! :P

Comment: It is some reference books. Am I asking too many questions?

Comment: Not at all! It must be a monster of a project though.

Comment: To reiterate, I'm not criticising. The whole point of Stack Exchange is the questions, so keep asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may define a very tiny font just like the standard font commands:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Tiny}{\@setfontsize\Tiny{3pt}{4pt}}
\makeatother
```

This may be used like `\Large` or `\large`. I've used 3pt here, because `\tiny` is already 5pt at article without size option. So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Tiny}{\@setfontsize\Tiny{5pt}{6pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{This text is normal {\Tiny This text is very tiny}}
\section{This text is normal {\tiny This text is tiny}}
\end{document}
```

Would show same font sizes.

BTW: Maybe package [relsize](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) would also be interesting for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\section{This text is normal {\relsize{-4} This text is very tiny}}
\end{document}
```

This allows to set sizes not absolute but relative.